# assign the value of for to the label in datatables

Tags: datatable

I have the following problem that returns to me in the Chrome console:

> A form field element should have an id or name attribute

It has to do with this code generated from the datatable search:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="daberto">
```

So to assign the name to the input, I used the following code:

```
$('.pedman1').dataTable({ 
  "oLanguage": {
      "search": $('input[type="search"]').attr ('name', 'tespesquisar')
  }
});
```

But then I go to the browser and continue to receive the same violation message:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="daberto" name="tespesquisar">
```

Can you help solve this problem?